# How to pass textbox values and what was the action to spring mvc controller?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am working on a Spring MVC controller project.

- First button is, `INSERT`. As soon as I click INSERT button, I am showing three text box just below the INSERT button. First textbox is `datacenter`, second textbox is `node` and third textbox is `data`.
- Second button is, `UPDATE`. As soon as I click UPDATE button, I am showing same above three text box just below the UPDATE button.
- Third button is, `DELETE`. As soon as I click DELETE button, I am showing only one text box just below the DELETE button. In this one text box will be `node`.
- Fourth button is, `PROCESS`. As soon as I click PROCESS button, I am showing four text box just below the PROCESS button. In this first textbox will be `datacenter`, second textbox will be `node`, third textbox will be `data` and fourth textbox will be `conf`

And lastly there will be submit button which I will be pressing.

And here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/13/) which has everything which I talked about above.

**Problem Statement:-**

Now what I need to do is, suppose if I am clicking `Insert` button first which will provide three text box just below the Insert button and then after typing some values in those three text box, I will be clicking `Submit` button which should pass the all those three text box values along with what action I did (meaning it was INSERT or UPDATE or DELETE or PROCESS) to my controller method `testOperations`. So for this case, if I typed `dc1` in datacenter, `hello` in node, `world` in data, then it should pass all these three values to my controller method but it should also pass `conf` value as null bcoz this textbox was not there for `Insert` button so when we press submit button, it should pass conf value as null to controller method.

Similarly If I click Delete button, then it will show only one text box below the Delete button and once I click Submit button, then it should pass Delete value as an action, datacenter value should be null, node value as the actual value we typed in the box, data value should be null as well and conf value should be null.. Similarly for others as well.

Below is my method in Controller code -

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "testOperation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, String> testOperation() {
        final Map<String, String> model = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "testOperation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, String> testOperations(@RequestParam String action,
                                              @RequestParam String datacenter, 
                                              @RequestParam String node, 
                                              @RequestParam String data,
                                              @RequestParam String conf) {
        final Map<String, String> model = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        System.out.println(action);
        System.out.println(datacenter);
        System.out.println(node);
        System.out.println(data);
        System.out.println(conf);

        return model;
    }
```

But somehow whenever I am pressing submit button after typing some values, it is giving me exception as Bad Request Exception.. And I know the reason why? Because suppose for the `Insert` case after typing values in those three textbox, I pressed Submit button, then conf value is not set and my controller method takes conf parameter so that is the reason it is throwing an exception.. And to fix this, I can remove the conf parameter but then for Process case, I need it..

So is there any way, I can pass null value for those text box which I don't need for certain buttons to controller to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options to solve your problem.

option 1) All the params that are not mandatory for all three actions, should be non-required, i.e:

> @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue=null) String conf

If you add "required=false" to all the non-mandatory params, you will not get the exception

option 2) make different controller methods for each operation, and make each method take only the required params for the specified operation:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "insertOperation", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public Map<String, String> insertOperation(
        @RequestParam String action,
        @RequestParam String datacenter, 
        @RequestParam String node, 
        @RequestParam String data
    ) {}
```

and:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "updateOperation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public Map<String, String> updateOperation(@RequestParam String action,
                                                  @RequestParam String datacenter, 
                                                  @RequestParam String node, 
                                                  @RequestParam String data,
                                                  @RequestParam String conf,
                                                  ) {}
```

Good luck!

Comment: But we can set default value as null in those forms right for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE and PROCESS? For those textboxs which we don't need right?

Comment: When the controller does not receive a "required=false" param, it is automatically null.

Comment: And i cannot have required=false.. Suppose I clicked Process button and for that I will be typing some value in that conf textbox and then press Submit button.. So in that case conf will have null value if I set it as required=false.

Comment: If you can't use required=false, split your controller methods so each operation will reach another method like in my second option.

Comment: I see.. There is no other way? Meaning setting the default value as null in the form itself for those textbox which we don't need it?

Comment: You can also add hidden fields to each form, that will contain no value (i.e <input type="hidden" name="conf" value="" />)

Comment: Look at my edited answer. I think it should cover all that you want. I've added defaultValue=null in option 1.

Comment: By the way, setting "required=false", doesn't mean it will always be null. ONLY IN CASE IT WAS NOT SENT BY THE FORM, it will be null.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49299/discussion-between-shay-elkayam-and-ssh)